# What is zero overhead principle in C++? Examples?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, compiler-construction

When I am reading [design goals of C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Design_goals), it mentioned about zero-overhead principle without any examples or features which uses this principle. I can understand that it could be there to avoid degrading existing code performance. But,

1. Can someone explain this concept with some examples?
2. Approach they made to implement such a feature in the standard?
3. How they enforce compiler-writers to implement this?

Comment: Straight from the [horse's mouth](http://www.stroustrup.com/ETAPS-corrected-draft.pdf): "In general, C++ implementations obey the
zero-overhead principle: What you don’t use, you don’t pay for [BS94]. And further: What you do use, you couldn’t hand code any better."

Comment: Number 3 is simple. Ridicule.

Comment: The addition of new C++11 features should not cause code that doesn't use those features to incur more overhead by them simply being introduced into the language is how I would interpret it, based on the way the wiki page is written.

Comment: @RSahu : Thank for the resource you added. Definitely worth reading.

Comment: @StoryTeller : Why it is simple? or you mean every feature is zero-overhead in every compiler as it is the standard?

Comment: B. Stroustrups article (mentioned by @RSahu) has a small example on page 4.

Comment: @Scheff : Reading the article... It might improve my understanding about this concept.

Comment: @PraAnj I suspect StoryTeller is (half) ironic; "ridicule" here is meant as imperative 2nd person singular of "to ridicule". He means that the enforcement is done by shaming/ridiculing compiler writers that provide low quality implementations, who should then fix them out of pride/shame. Generally works when the shaming is done by someone famous.

Comment: The standard attempts to make it possible for compiler/library implementers to avoid overhead for unused features. With only a handful of annoying exceptions, the library specifications never require an implementation to track unnecessary metadata. For example, there is deliberately no mechanism to extract the filename of an open file, so the implementation has no reason to do so. But the standard does not say to implentors: "you must make your implementation as fast as possible." *We* (collectively, or in aggregate) do that when we choose which implementation we will use.